# Should I contact the hiring manager?

Tags: recruitment, manager, linkedin, hiring

I applied to a job I was interested in through a recruiter. I had the interview with the recruiter a couple of days later and she told me she will pass my resume + portfolio to the client and its up to them to schedule an interview. That same day I kept my job search and saw a job posting, same company and position. Would it be wrong to message him on linkedin asking for an interview?

I dont want to go behind the recruiters back but I also want to make a good impression and land an interview.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good idea going behind the recruiters back. It looks very bad. The recruiters and the company will probably have a long relationship with each other and the potential employer will spot this.

This will say to the new employer that you do things that are shady.

I would just call the recruiter and ask for a status update. They may just meet up once a week with a collection of CVs and chat able the candidates then.